# What does babel do while webpack is working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I find out that `webpack` is using `@babel/core` and `@babel/preset-react` and `babel-loader` via [its package.json](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/package.json).

So I'm wondering what these **built-in** packages have done as `webpack` works?

> p.s. I'm not talking about Loaders/Plugins that should be added manually to `webpack.config.js`.

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Those are not built-in and they are dev dependencies, so not used while weback "works", they are used to develop webpack and probably there for the same reasons other projects use them, to transpile one version of ecmascript to another.

Comment: @morganney So webpack just using these babel packages to transpile the ecmascript version right? Does webpack also use them to tree-shake modules?